# History login data for oracle 8.1.7.4

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, oracle8i

How can I view history login data from oracle 8.1.7.4.

I need to view login dates of a certain user, is this possible from oracle 8.1.7.4. ?

Comment: Yes, if you configured the database to [AUDIT SESSION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107) which tracks the logins of users. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50524). Note that I have linked to the 11gR2 docs, because 8i is too archaic to easily find its docs. However, AUDIT has been standard functionality since forever, so you shouldn't have any difficulty applying it.

Comment: This may be a simpler guide to follow https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/auditing